# Difference of writing jinja2 macro in one line V.S. writing macro in multiple lines?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have next jinja2 template:

**cfg.jinja2:**

```
{% macro cfg() %}ABC{% endmacro %}
{% macro cfg2() %}
ABC
{% endmacro %}

resource:
{{ cfg()|indent(4) }}
{{ cfg2()|indent(4) }}
```

And, next python file:

**test.py:**

```
import os
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

path_dir = "."
loader = FileSystemLoader(searchpath=path_dir)
env = Environment(loader=loader)
template = env.get_template("cfg.jinja2")
data = template.render()
print(data)
```

It shows next result:

```
$ python3 test.py



resource:
ABC

    ABC
```

I wonder, why `cfg()` has no effect with `indent filter` while `cfg2()` works as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`indent` docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.indent):

> Return a copy of the string with each line indented by 4 spaces. The first line and blank lines are not indented by default.

`cfg()` returns a single line: `"ABC"`. The first line is not indented.

`cfg2()` returns three lines, first and last of which are empty: `"\nABC\n"`. The empty lines not being indented, the result has the second line indented: `"\n    ABC\n"`.

The reason `cfg()` and `cfg2()` have different outputs is because `cfg2` has two newlines in its definition: `"{% macro cfg2() %}\nABC\n{% endmacro %}"`.

You could force your first example to also indent: `{{ cfg()|indent(4, first=True) }}`; it will result in output similar, but not identical to that of `cfg2()`: `"    ABC"` (but without the two newlines).

Comment: So, when it set `first` default as `False`, can you kindly suggest what it try to avoid? What scenario it try to resolve to add such `switch` here? Thanks, of course just a side question, for my knowledge.

Comment: I have a guess, but it is only that: a guess (placing the indented string into a document in an already indented line). But the "why" of it is not as important as knowing that this is how it works, so you can use it correctly.